# Adding name on the top of signature line in footer

Tags: formatting, signatures

I wish to add the name of my guide manually on the footer section for 'signature' on my document. I am using the document class report and this page constitutes the undertaking part of my thesis.

I am attaching the code for reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\LARGE  CERTIFICATE \  FROM \ GUIDE}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5in}
I certify that the thesis entitled \textit{"How to add the name on signature footer"} submitted by  mnuizhre for the award of SE degree, embodies original work done by him under my guidance.
\\
\\
This work has not been submitted to this or any other institute for the award of any other degree.
\newline
\newline
\vspace{2in}

\parbox{2in}{{\color{gray}\rule{1in}{1pt}}\\%
   Date}\hfill\parbox{2in}
%\\
{{\color{gray}\rule{2in}{2pt}}\\%
   Dr. Rorty Mick, \vfill Professor, \vfill Doofenshmirtz E Inc. \\\mbox{}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Above the line where Dr. Rorty Mick is written I want to type his name i.e. Rorty Mike since the signature of him is not available at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: Write it just before the rule command and then insert the new line: `foooo\\ \rule{1in}{1pt}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution with some improvements in the code (quotes, for example).

Adjust the vertical spaces as you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}\LARGE
    \textbf{CERTIFICATE FROM GUIDE}
\end{center}

\bigskip

I certify that the thesis entitled \textit{``How to add the name on signature footer''} submitted by  mnuizhre for the award of SE degree, embodies original work done by him under my guidance.

\medskip

This work has not been submitted to this or any other institute for the award of any other degree.

\vfill

\noindent
\parbox[t]{2in}{%
  \vphantom{Rorty}\\[-.5\baselineskip] %% to adjust vertical space
  {\color{gray}\rule{1in}{1pt}}\\
  Date%
} \hfill 
\parbox[t]{2in}{%
Rorty Mick\\[-.5\baselineskip]
{\color{gray}\rule{2in}{1pt}}\\%
Dr.\ Rorty Mick,\\ 
Professor,\\ 
Doofenshmirtz E Inc.
} 
\end{document}
```